# Joining table to istelf is very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have a table that can be connected to itself. I want to connect it twice. Here's the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `route_connections` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `from_route_iid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `from_service_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `to_route_iid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `to_service_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `to_route` (`to_route_iid`),
    KEY `from_route` (`from_route_iid`),
    KEY `to_service` (`to_service_id`),
    KEY `from_service` (`from_service_id`),
    KEY `from_to_route` (`from_route_iid`,`to_route_iid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6798783 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

It has around 3.7M rows.

My main goal is to find a path that uses 3 routes (2 route connections), knowing the list of allowed departure and arrival route (the connecting route has to be determined by the query).

Path: route A → route B → route C:

- departure routes (known list, A)
- `route_connection` c1 (A → B)
- connecting route (unknown, B)
- `route_connection` c2 (B → C)
- arrival routes (known list, C)

So I need to select three `route_iid`s: `c1.from`, `c1.to` or `c2.from` (which is the same) and `c2.to`.

Also, I need to filter every `service_id` using the following filter:

```
service_id in (
    select service_id from (
        select service_id from calendar c
            where c.start_date <= 20141109 and end_date >= 20141109 

        union

        select service_id from calendar_dates cd 
            where cd.date = 20141109 and exception_type = 1 
    ) x 
    where x.service_id not in (
        select service_id from calendar_dates cd 
        where cd.date = 20141109 and exception_type = 2
    )
)
```

First I'm working on the connecting routes without taking care of the `service_id` filtering.

When searching for only one connection, the query takes <1ms (zero results):

```
select c.*
from route_connections c
where c.from_route_iid in (864, 865, 495, 494, 459, 54, 458)
    and c.to_route_iid in (745, 744, 1096, 1093, 743, 317, 742, 13, 316)
```

But my goal is to find 2 connections, so I'm using this query, which takes a lot of time (zero results aswell):

```
select c1.*, c2.*
from
route_connections c1
inner join route_connections c2 on c2.from_route_iid = c1.to_route_iid
    and c2.to_route_iid in (745, 744, 1096, 1093, 743, 317, 742, 13, 316)
where c1.from_route_iid in (864, 865, 495, 494, 459, 54, 458)
```

It used to take 50 seconds, but I added the `from_to_route` index, which sped up the query to 18-20 seconds.

I also tried not using joins:

```
SELECT ...
FROM route_connections c1, route_connections c2
WHERE ...
```

but it yields the exact same performance (I guess that internally it's exactly the same as the join).

I tried to change the inner join to a left join + a `HAVING` clause, but it was much much worse (as expected).

I tried to remove all indexes but these two:

- PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
- KEY `from_route_iid` (`from_route_iid`,`to_route_iid`)

The result is the same, around 18-20s.

Here's the explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------+----------------+---------+----------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                      | key            | key_len | ref                              | rows  | Extra                            |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------+----------------+---------+----------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c1    | range | to_route,from_route,from_route_iid | from_route     | 4       | NULL                             | 15464 | Using index condition; Using MRR |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c2    | ref   | to_route,from_route,from_route_iid | from_route_iid | 4       | bicou_gtfs_paris.c1.to_route_iid |  1746 | Using index condition            |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------+----------------+---------+----------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------+
```

What is the correct way to join the table to itself? Did I miss an index or anything?

The hardware is a 2014 macbook air, with a 1.7GHz Core i7, 8GB of RAM and a 256GB SSD.
The software is Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite, with MySQL 5.6.21

Comment: What are the different index on this table?

Comment: They're shown in the `CREATE TABLE` statement. Basically all fields are indexed individually, there's an index for from/to route ID, and I used to have a `UNIQUE` index on the 4 fields (except the PK) but I have removed it to see the impact on the performance.

Comment: Why use joins when you have a working query without joins?

Comment: Your question mentions `SELECT c1.*, c2.*`. Please consider changing that to instead enumerate the exact columns you need in your result set. Knowing which columns are required is a good start towards optimizing your query with so-called *compound covering indexes.*

Comment: @OllieJones: right, but it's slightly more complicated. Also, I'll select every field but the PK, so it's almost the same as `*`. I have updated my question.

Comment: @EmmadKareem: both queries (with and without join) yield the same result with the same performance, which is what I want to improve. 20 seconds is not an option for me, I'm looking for something <5s, ideally <1s.

Comment: What is the expected result? Try creating compound indexes (from_route, to_route) and (to_route, from_route)

Comment: The result I'm getting it what I'm expecting, I just want to run this query faster.

Comment: Another suggestion: try dropping individual indexes for both to and from or force use of the compound index. Also mention which version of MySQL you are running

Comment: @Sami: same result (around 20s). I have added more information. I'm using MySQL 5.6.

Comment: Try looking at qcgraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here's how I found the solution:

```
select to_route_iid
from route_connections
where from_route_iid in (864, 865, 495, 494, 459, 54, 458)
```

=> 15471 rows

```
select to_route_iid
from route_connections
where from_route_iid in (864, 865, 495, 494, 459, 54, 458)
group by to_route_iid
```

=> 97 rows!

It's the same for the arrival routes, 131 grouped rows vs 25427.

So this query:

```
select c1.from_route_iid, c2.from_route_iid, c2.to_route_iid
from (
    select from_route_iid, to_route_iid
    from route_connections
    where from_route_iid in (864, 865, 495, 494, 459, 54, 458)
    group by to_route_iid
) c1, route_connections c2
where c2.from_route_iid = c1.to_route_iid
and c2.to_route_iid in (745, 744, 1096, 1093, 743, 317, 742, 13, 316)
group by c2.from_route_iid, c2.to_route_iid
```

runs in 145ms. That's nice, this morning I started at 2 minutes :)